# How to make expect timestamp logfile

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to make my expect script to create one log file with a timestamp and create another with timestamp next time it runs but can't find any info on how.

I have a file with a list of hosts that expect connects to and run a set of command that I want to log all events from in one file when it runs.

```
Host1
Host2
Host3
etc
```

I have manage to create log file with timestamp:

```
log_file -a ~/log/[exec date]_results.log
```

Also tried with:

```
log_file -a -noappend ~/log/[exec date]_results.log
```

But it creates a new one for every line of hosts:

```
Thu Mar  8 15:28:24 CET 2018_results.log
Thu Mar  8 15:28:25 CET 2018_results.log
Thu Mar  8 15:28:26 CET 2018_results.log
Thu Mar  8 15:28:27 CET 2018_results.log
Thu Mar  8 15:28:28 CET 2018_results.log
```

I found one solution.

Added this to my .sh

```
timestamp=`date +%y-%m-%d_%H:%M`
logdir=~/log/

# This will rotate and append date stamp...
logfile=$logdir/results.log
newlogfile=$logfile.$timestamp
cp $logfile $newlogfile
```

This works but will only add timestamp to the rotated file, the results.log file will be the newest one and and the rotated file will be stamped with date and time from when you run the script, so the timestamp of that file will be wrong.

Here are both .sh and .exp scripts if there is a solution to timestamp all the files with the correct date/time.

.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
 # Collect the current user's ssh password file to copy.
 echo -n "Enter the telnet password for $(whoami) : "
 read -s -e password
 echo -ne '\n'
 echo -n "Enter the command to run on device : "
 read -e command
 echo -ne '\n'

timestamp=`date +%y-%m-%d_%H:%M`
logdir=~/log/

# This will rotate and append date stamp...
logfile=$logdir/results.log
newlogfile=$logfile.$timestamp
cp $logfile $newlogfile

names=()
ips=()
n=0
while read name ip; do
  [[ -z $ip ]] && continue
  names[n]=$name
  ips[n]=$ip
  ((++n))
done < hostlist

for ((i=0; i<n; ++i)); do
  ./script.exp ${names[i]} ${ips[i]} $device "$password" "$command"
done
```

.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Set variables
 set hostname [lindex $argv 0]
 set ipadd    [lindex $argv 1]
 set username $env(USER)
 set password [lindex $argv 2]
 set command  [lindex $argv 3]
 set timeout 20
# Log results
 log_file -a ~/log/results.log            
# Announce which device we are working on and at what time
 send_user "\n"
 send_user ">>>>>  Working on $hostname @ [exec date] <<<<<\n"
 send_user "\n"

 expect_after timeout {send_user "Timeout happened connecting to $hostname; So, exiting....";exit 0}

 spawn telnet $hostname
 expect "*sername:"
 send   "$username\n"
 expect "*assword:"
 send "$password\n"
 expect "*#"
 send "$command $ipadd\n"
 expect "*#"
 send "exit\n"
 expect ":~\$"
 exit
```

Comment: Your code, please.

Comment: Sorry about missing code, Please see answer @EmilyE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all of this from within Expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set host_file "hostlist"
if {![file readable $host_file]} {
    error "cannot read $host_file"
}

# get info from user
set me [exec whoami]
stty -echo
send_user "Enter the telnet password for $me : "
expect_user -re {(.*)\n}
set password $expect_out(1,string)
send_user "\n"
stty echo

send_user "Enter the command to run on device : "
expect_user -re {(.*)\n}
set command $expect_out(1,string)

set timestamp [timestamp -format %Y-%m-%d_%H:%M]
set logfile $env(HOME)/log/results_$timestamp.log
log_file -a $logfile

expect_after timeout {send_user "Timeout happened connecting to $hostname; So, exiting....";exit 0}

set fh [open $host_file r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    lassign [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line] hostname ip
    if {$hostname eq "" || $ip eq ""} continue

    send_user "\n"
    send_user ">>>>>  Working on $hostname @ [timestamp -format %c] <<<<<\n"
    send_user "\n"

    spawn telnet $hostname
    expect "*sername:"
    send   "$me\r"
    expect "*assword:"
    send   "$password\r"
    expect "*#"
    send   "$command $ip\r"
    expect "*#"
    send   "exit\r"
    expect eof
}
```

---

To handle timeouts for user input, there are 2 strategies:

1. set the `timeout` variable to `-1` to wait indefinitely:

   ```
   set prev_timeout $timeout
   set timeout -1
   send_user "Enter the thing: "
   expect_user -re "(.*)\n"            ;# waits forever
   set the_thing $expect_out(1,string)
   set timeout $prev_timeout
   ```
2. use an infinite loop to provide feedback to the user

   ```
   while 1 {
       send_user "Enter the thing: "
       expect_user {
           -re "(.*)\n" {break}
           timeout {send_error "timeout!\n"}
       }
   }
   set the_thing $expect_out(1,string)
   ```

Comment: Did not get this to work, but used the log code with my expect script and that works perfectly! Thank you! Will try to tweak your suggestion to make it work to learn more about expect.

Comment: While you're developing expect code, add `exp_internal 1`to the top of your script for debugging

Comment: tnx. With debug on i figured out that the variable in `set fh [open $hostlist r]` Should read `$host_file`. Another thing i found is that the script timeout while typing password or the command.
`expect: timed out
can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such variable
    while executing
"set password $expect_out(1,string)"
    (file "./conf_cisco.exp" line 14)
tty_set: raw = 5, echo = 0`